# Programmatically creating the policyid / scripthash in Javascript (Browser)

Tags: cardano-cli, policy, javascript, cbor, blake2b

I'm looking for a Javascript implementation of the CLI's `cardano-cli transaction policyid` function, can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Trying to replicate it with blakejs (https://github.com/dcposch/blakejs) and cbor-web (https://github.com/hildjj/node-cbor/tree/main/packages/cbor-web), but failing to get the hashes to match the output of the CLI.

*Eg I want to create a PolicyID / ScriptHash from this policy script:*

```
{
  "type": "all",
  "scripts":
  [
   {
     "type": "before",
     "slot": 42863577
   },
   {
     "type": "sig",
     "keyHash": "46a26617f9b59cc48945ccc6c0aecee732f7698fadbe8b5624b44b9e"
   }
  ]
}
```

*(CLI gives me this policyid: 463e9264962cea64efafa576d44c8d2821d09c0c7495c253d4101a9a)*

In JS I'm trying something along these lines:

```
[removed, see correct answer below]
```

*(gives me this: 5db35cd45775e7d7b0d1bd5491a9baea7ac54b41772a8c96ce587579)*

Any guidance is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the 10.0 beta version of `cardano-serialization-lib` which should make it into stable pretty soon (I'm in the process of testing this, you can follow the status on [this Github issue](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/141)).

This should be enough to get you started:

```
const ttl = protocolParameters.slot+invalidHereafter
const timelockExpiry = S.TimelockExpiry.new(ttl)
const timeLockedPolicyScript = S.NativeScript.new_timelock_expiry(timelockExpiry)
const policyScripts = S.NativeScripts.new()
const policyScripts.add(timeLockedPolicyScript)
const scriptHash = S.ScriptHash.from_bytes(timeLockedPolicyScript.hash().to_bytes())
const policyID = bytesToString(timeLockedPolicyScript.hash().to_bytes())
```

In order for that code to work, you'll need some valid protocolParameters object which can be retrieved from Blockfrost using [this code from Nami wallet](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet/blob/58c924cfd98fd568ed2ff133d95fde16771e81d8/src/api/extension/wallet.js#L20), as well as the `bytesToString` function which is defined using Buffer:

```
export const bytesToString = (bytes) => {
  return Buffer.from(bytes, "hex").toString("hex")
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, that looks pretty elegant! 

Answer (score 3):

Finally got my head around this, thanks to this version in Python: [Re-Implementing Policy Hashing in Python](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/486/re-implementing-policy-hashing-in-python) by @tycl.

Basically we need to

1. Parse the policy (JSON)
2. Follow the CDDL specifications to translate the policy to an array
   *(see link below)*
3. Use the array as input to cbor.encode().
4. Prepend a "0" byte to the result.
5. Run that new byte array through blake2bHex.

And we're done.

Here's an example:

The policy used is the one from above and I translate it manually to the array via https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/683bef2e40cbd10339452c9f2009867c855baf1a/shelley-ma/shelley-ma-test/cddl-files/shelley-ma.cddl#L228-L246;

Cbor-Web used from here: https://github.com/hildjj/node-cbor/tree/main/packages/cbor-web

Blakejs package from here: https://github.com/dcposch/blakejs

```
// Values from policy json
const keyhash = "46a26617f9b59cc48945ccc6c0aecee732f7698fadbe8b5624b44b9e";
const slot = 42863577;

// Translation via CDDL link above
// [1, [X]] => "script_all"
// [5, slot] => "invalid_hereafter" (~ "valid before")
// [0, keyHashBytes] => "script_pubkey"
// Remember: 1) Buffer conversion and 2) Order matters.
const cborInput = [1, [[5, slot], [0, Buffer.from(hexToBytes(keyhash))]]]

// Cbor encode
let cborResult = cbor.encode(cborInput);

// Prepend the 0 byte
let tmp = new Uint8Array(cborResult.length + 1);
tmp.set(Uint8Array.of(0), 0);
tmp.set(cborResult, 1);
cborResult = tmp;

// Run the result through blake2d with digest size / output length of 28
const blakeHexResult = Blake.blake2bHex(cborResult, null, 28);
console.log(blakeHexResult);
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for linking to cddl!